# flurry.com says 'pending' for the bberry app stats

Tags: blackberry-storm

Every one. I want to integrate my BlackBerry app with the Flurry Library.so, I just added the FlurryAgent.jar file to the build path and then added life cycle methods in the each screen.
But  flurry.com says 'pending' for the bberry app stats
Can any one help me ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

for reference. the pending is on the new users field. the way they are calculated need some time to compare the users of this week vs the users of previous week(s) so by time it should change to a valid number.
nothing to worry about